# Create top ten list

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to build an iPhone app where I have a list of names, and can search by year to find the top ten names for that year.  How would I need to set that up in xcode?

Comment: Select "New Project..." and work your way from there

Comment: You will get better answers stating what you have tried to do already and asking for help with any issues you have encountered. Don't be put off by the down votes the project is very doable you just need to build from a solid foundation, and that at the moment is learning how to build a simple iphone application and taking it from there.

Comment: The downvotes are because you say "I'm trying", but showing no evidence of that. Nobody here is going to do it for you, but the guidance you will get here if you actually bring us what you've been working on is absolutely incredible.

Answer (score 2):

You say you are new to iphone development so you can start with this [primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

After that I recommend you build a simple web service using your platform and language of choice in your application get the input and make a web service call to the webservice.

You could improve your application by having it work offline and use a local database for its data.

Both approaches will work.